# What is "gate count" in synthesis result and how to calculate

Tags: vhdl, verilog, area, synthesis

I'm synthesizing my design with design compiler and have some comparison with another design (as a evaluation in my report). The Synopsys's tool can easily report the area with command but in all paper I've read care about **gate count**.

My quiz is what is **gate count** and how to calculate it?

I googled and heard about **gate count** is calculated as `total_area/NAND2_area`. So, is it true?

Thank for your reading and please don't blame me about stupid question :(.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Synthesised area is often quoted as Gate count in NAND2 equivalents. You are correct with:

```
(total area)/(NAND2 area).
```

Older tools and libraries use to report this number, a few years a go I noticed a shift for tools to just provide areas in Square Microns. However the gate count is a nicer number to get your head around, and the number is portable between different size geometries.

40K for implementation A is smaller than 50K for implementation B. Much harder to compare 100000 um^2 for implementation A process X vs 65000 um^2 for implementation B on process y.

Comment: I don't have any information of previous designs (only gate count on these papers) for comparison and as you said,  it's easier for compare various technologies. Thank for your answer.